# When did $foo->$bar['bippo'] stop to work? so access to a object field via variable that is an array in php

Tags: php, php-7

So I just found a bug in our code:

```php
$foo->$bar['bippo']
```

It used to work, but we are on `PHP7` now and it only works if you do:

```php
$baz = $bar['bippo'];
$foo->$baz;
```

- Is it PHP version problem or bug from the past?
- Is there a way to find these kind of bugs in `PHP7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use braces:

```
$foo->{$bar['bippo']}
```

See [PHP RFC: Uniform Variable Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax#semantic_differences_in_existing_syntax)